# Display sum after each row

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I am using MySQL and need to display the sum of all the previous values, including the current row, for each row.

```
date | val | total  
------------------  
15M  | 20  |  20
17M  | 15  |  35
1APR | -5  |  30
-------------------
```

So, in the database I only have the `date` and the `val` for each date. I currently use `SELECT date, val FROM table ORDER BY DATE ASC`. How can I also add the `total` column? I guess I would use a `SUM` query, but how do I add the sum for every row?

Comment: maybe `select date, val, qty, @s:=@s+total as subtotal from mytable`

Comment: SELECT * FROM my_table;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you can use a variable, you can easily calculate cumulative sum
 this way

```
set @csum := 0;
select date, val, (@csum := @csum + val) as cumulative_sum
from table
order by date DESC;
```

**EDIT** There is a way to define your variable in a join

```
select t.date, t.val, (@csum := @csum + t.val) as cumulative_sum
from table t
join (select @csum := 0) r
order by date DESC;
```

Comment: `In case you can use a variable` . Why couldn't I use a variable?

Comment: I'm not sure. It depends on what library or SQL client you use.

Comment: It works. My only problem is that the total is calculated by `date`, `ascending`, but I have to display the results in descending order (newest entries first). Can I do the sum in ascending order and then sort the results in descending order?

Comment: Descending order, sure, I have modified the answer accordingly

Comment: Yes, but if I make the sum descending, the total does not make sense. Because the total is computed in chronological order (2014 value 1, 2015 value 4). If I display in ascending the total is correct (2014 - total 1, 2015 - total 5). But if I display in descending order it's wrong (2015 - total 4, 2014 total 5). So, the `total` will be computed in ascending order, but I have to show the table results in descending order (while keeping the total values).

Comment: Fixed it, thank you. Added an outer `SELECT * FROM` this query, so I re-order the results descending.